# How to read a zip file in R and iterate through each .txt file to convert it into .cvs?

Tags: r, csv

I have a zip file having `.txt` documents. I want to unzip the file in R and convert the text documents into `.csv` so that I can use it for further analysis.

Can I give the header names while converting?

Further I also want to iterate the process by writing a function to read each above converted .csv file and generate basic graphs from the data. Is it feasible to do this in R?

For instance lets consider zip file name as 'data.zip' having 5 text files(1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, 4.txt, 5.txt). Each text file has log information on a single row with IP, date and time.

```
111.999.88.80 - - [27/Mar/2017:00:03:16 -0600] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1"
```

Your answers will be of great help. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: why bother converting them to csv files?  Why not read the .txt file and do your analysis?

Comment: Well I had this in mind but I don't know how to use the data without headers as I have not dealt with text files before.

Also even If I do that I would like to know if I can iterate the process of reading the file and plotting the graph?

Comment: The best answer I can give you without a sample zip file is "yes."  To get you started, look at the `unzip` function to unzip the files, use `list.files` to get the file names, and then use `read.table` to read each file.  You can use the `header=FALSE` argument to read in data without column names.  You'll need to add column names of your own (or at least I recommend it) using the `names` function.  Tie all of that into a `for` loop or an `apply` function and you can iterate over all of the files in the zip folder.

Comment: Can you give an example? It would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

I create a reproducible sample.

And think this may solve your problem.

You can download the sample zip file I created from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hebuxw8wh8a4ali/text.zip?raw=1).

Attached is the full codes.

```
## Clean Memory
rm(list=ls())

## Set path for your working location
setwd("D:/blah")

## unzipped it the file
unzip("D:/blah/text.zip")

## Check file in the zipped file
list.files()

## Read the file
temp = list.files(pattern="*.txt")
```

There is options here.  I think what you want is the second one which combines the two files in the sample and merge them into one.

```
## Read the file as list
myfiles= lapply(temp, read.delim)
## Read the file all together
myfiles = do.call("rbind", lapply(temp, function(x) read.table(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,header = TRUE)))
```

Make sure to adjust the header setting if needed.
Alrighty, good luck.