# Processing data in a file wrapped under multiple zip files in R

Tags: r, data-analysis

How to read data from a below url in R

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/eeg-mld/

Here the file to be processed is wrapped under multiple zip files. I could parse until one zip file level but when trying to read the final zip file I could not do it as it is showing no file found error.

Can anyone help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which of the files do you mean? please show us the code you have tried so far.

Comment: considering this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31997383/6779509), replace `temp = list.files(pattern="*.txt")` by `pattern="*.zip"` might kinda work

Answer (score 0):

With a zip wrapped in a zip in a zip ... I tried this: You can unzip the files by iteration into your home dir.

```
foo <- unzip(zipfile = "path/to/your/zipfile.zip")
while(tools::file_ext(foo) == "zip"){
  foo <- unzip(zipfile = foo)
}
```

Afterwards, you can use `foo` to do what ever you want, e.g. read a table.

```
bar <- read.table(foo)
```